# How to use UTF-8 in PDFKit in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm using PDFKit in my Rails app to generate PDF's. Problem is some of my content in contains non-ascii characters. How do I force it to use UTF-8?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fixed by adding this to in the html head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Works for the Python pdfkit as well. `html = '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />' + str(msg.html)`

Answer (score 3):

```
You can write in PDFKIT configration.

 PDFKit.configure do |config|
        config.wkhtmltopdf = '/opt/wkhtmltopdf'
        config.default_options = {
          :encoding      => 'UTF-8'
          :page_size     => 'Letter',
          :margin_top    => '0.3in',          
          :margin_bottom => '0.1in',          
          :print_media_type => true                       
        }
 end
```

Comment: can you please add link to the docs that explain how to do that ?

Comment: I have written above in config/initializers/pdfkit.rb file (ROR App). And It is working fine for me. I did this by  using https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf document

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329282/how-to-load-images-precompiled-assets-with-pdfkit-wkhtmltopdf-rails-5-2

Comment: `utf-8` is the default value for `encoding` key anyway https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/blob/master/lib/pdfkit/configuration.rb#L19