# PDFKit with Rails creates malformatted text using render_to_string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, pdfkit

I am using PDFKit to render a partial view as a PDF file.  However, I'm running into some issues when trying to use render_to_string (preferred method), rather than an external web request.

**The pdf file when rendered using a url:**

```
html = "#{root_url}/contracts/#{@contract.id}"
pdf = PDFKit.new(html, page_size: 'Letter').to_pdf
```

[image: Proper Text]

**The pdf file when rendered using render_to_string:**

```
html = render_to_string :partial => "agreement"
pdf = PDFKit.new(html , page_size: 'Letter').to_pdf
*from the console*
html => "\n\n<style>\n  #contract h2{text-align: center; margin-bottom: 10px;}\n  #contract em{font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; font-style: normal;}\n  #contract p.tab{margin-left: 25px;}\n  #contract ol{list-style:lower-alpha;}\n  #contract ol li{margin-left: 25px; font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.615em; color: #555; margin-bottom: 5px;}\n  #contract b{font-weight: bold;}\n  #contract p p{margin-left: 10px;}\n</style>\n<div id=\"contract\">\n <p>This agreement (“<b>Agreement</b>”) is entered into...
```

[image: Malformatted Text]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are likely trying to show unicode symbols (quotes) within the page having `ASCII` encoding. The problem has nothing to do with `pdf`, add `<meta encoding="utf-8">` in your html’s `head`.

Comment: I tried, and that doesn't seem to do the trick.  The same html is provided to the PDFKit in both cases, yet only one has the poor encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have curved quotes in the source partial. The console output shows this:

```
...<p>This agreement (“<b>Agreement</b>”)...
```

Curved quotes are UTF-8 characters, however PDFKit is parsing them as ASCII by default. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367187/how-to-use-utf-8-in-pdfkit-in-rails).

---

**EDIT**: Passing in a directly-rendered string requires the string to use UTF-8 encoding. Ruby 1.9 does this by default. In Ruby 1.8, try the following:

```
html = render_to_string :partial => "agreement", :encoding => "UTF-8"
```

Comment: I've tried adding the encoding above as shown in your edit, as well as passing in "html.toutf8()" directly into the PDFKit. Neither appear to work :-/

Comment: I added <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> to the html header as suggested in the link you provided, and it did work. Thanks!

Comment: Adding the meta tag into the <head> from the comment above, worked very nicely for me as well :)