# How to load images/precompiled assets with PDFKit/wkhtmltopdf? Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, activerecord, pdfkit, rails-activestorage

I'm having some success with creating PDFs with PDFKit, but the images are not loading from active_storage and assets resources. It fails every single time that I create the PDF, using show.pdf.erb. I'm using the default image_tag and assets are precompiled for production. How can I get PDFKit to find the precompiled assets folder for the images, and also find active_storage images that are supposed to load within the show.pdf.erb view? It works perfectly fine in the normal show.html.erb action. I'm using Windows 10 Pro x64. All styles are embedded in the style html tag/block on the page itself.

**server development log**

```
Rendered books/show.pdf.erb (338.2ms)
Loading pages (1/6)
Warning: Failed to load file:///rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBHQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--4528619d26f56f1272afd5cd7641c666137e55e3/book-wallpaper.jpg (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///assets/book_assets/book_white_pendant_50x50-8bf2d07feef7eeec22156e327c618aa02b531c2b7df4eb42308121ce55749b12.png (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBHUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--bb21bd1f8363f10691f76d305829078e20c66c13/cookies.jpg (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///assets/book_assets/user_photo_white40x40-2b2a6064512b3fc938bd24dc94f813bc96a259c9c68e53e6fc101cb7db758aa0.png (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///assets/book_assets/published-icon-888d2e09f6bd152718c2b03ee0ad753e766a2fc767fea6f932f539185a1a29ad.png (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///assets/book_assets/unpublished_icon_white_40x40-e05d35d6e8818e7a06aad4c86c0a6f213d7d1c1461905ce4f612e8562a6995eb.png (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///assets/book_assets/book_search_icon_50x50-184ff833a61c48ebd7fc5e728c0de77aaee09720ebae47ab86535850eb03c350.png (ignore)
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done                                                                      
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Sent data Jamie-book-pjxr6Fu4sJC1.pdf (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7351ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 466.2ms)
```

**image tags**

```
<%= image_tag "book_assets/user_photo_white40x40" %>
```

**active_storage**

```
<%= image_tag url_for(@book.profile_photo), class: 'd-flex align-self-start mr-3 img-fluid' %>
```

**books_controller.rb**

```
 def show
    impressionist(@book)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do

        html = render_to_string(:action => "show.pdf.erb")
        kit = PDFKit.new(html)
        send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => "book-info.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => "inline")
      end
    end
  end
```

**initializers/pdfkit.rb**

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  if ["development"].include?(Rails.env)
config.wkhtmltopdf = ENV['WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH'] || "C:\\wkhtml_setup\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe"
  else
    #if your site is hosted on heroku or any other hosting server which is 64bit
    config.wkhtmltopdf = Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-amd64').to_s
  end

  config.verbose = true
      config.default_options = {
      :encoding=>"UTF-8",
      :page_size=>"A4", #or "Letter" or whatever needed
      :margin_top=>"0in",
      :margin_right=>"0in",
      :margin_bottom=>"0in",
      :margin_left=>"0in",
      :disable_smart_shrinking => false
  }
end
```

Comment: Can you please try this `<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag "book_assets/user_photo_white40x40" %>`

Comment: I can’t install wicked_pdf on my Windows platform. Pyt doesn’t work. Does this answer require it??

Comment: I think you need to mention `root_url` for PDFkit, please check this https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit#resolving-relative-urls-and-protocols

Comment: Thanks Vishal, I will post the correct answer.

Comment: Glad to know your issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

The quickest method to solving this problem is using the initializer approach.

**initializers/pdfkit.rb**

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  if ["development"].include?(Rails.env)
    config.wkhtmltopdf = ENV['WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH'] || "C:\\wkhtml_setup\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe"
  end

    config.root_url = "#{Rails.root.join('public')}/"
    config.verbose = true
    config.default_options = {
       :print_media_type => true,
       dpi: 400
  }
end
```